# Changing the title of post with code

Tags: themes

Am actually new to wordpress development. I am just trying to change title of the individual post..So i have used the function `get_the_ID()` to fetch a specific post.

I know the name of the title can be changed by a user manually,But i just want to weather this can be done with the code.

So i have tried adding a function in `functions.php`

```
function afunction( $post )
{
if ( empty ( $post->post_title ) )
    return;

$new_title = mb_convert_case( $post->post_title, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8" );

if ( $post->post_title === $new_title )
    return;

wp_update_post(
    array (
        'ID'         => $post->ID,
        'post_title' => $new_title
    )
);

// $post is passed by reference, so we update this property in real time
$post->post_title = $new_title;
}
```

So in my `index.php` the code looks like

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>




                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                    <div class="single-post-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                            <br><br>
<?php  echo afunction( $post ) ?>
                    <?php
                    $hon = array(
                        'post_title' => 'asad'
                        );
                 $name = get_the_ID();
                 if($name  == 19) {
                  $post->title = 'sfsdf';
                  echo $post->title;
                 }
                 ?>



            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Thanx for your valuable help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question isn't terribly clear, because, yes it is possible to change post data programmatically, and you're on the right track using wp_update_post, but I'm unsure of what the code in your theme's index.php file is trying to achieve.

My assumption is that you want to be able to change the post title from your theme, but you're not passing anything to afunction() to update it.

Also, in your function above, when you call mb_convert_case, you're also re-defining $new_title as the original post title, so when $post->post_title === $new_title is executed, it always equates to true.

To achieve what I think you're trying to achieve, I would do something like this:

In functions.php:

```
function afunction( $post, $new_title ) {
  // if new_title isn't defined, return
  if ( empty ( $new_title ) ) {
      return;
  }    

  // ensure title case of $new_title
  $new_title = mb_convert_case( $new_title, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8" );

  // if $new_title is defined, but it matches the current title, return
  if ( $post->post_title === $new_title ) {
      return;
  }

  // place the current post and $new_title into array
  $post_update = array(
    'ID'         => $post->ID,
    'post_title' => $new_title
  );

  wp_update_post( $post_update );
}
```

**Updated:** In your theme file (index.php, page.php, single.php, etc):

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

   <h2>
       <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
   </h2>

   <div class="single-post-content">
       <?php the_content(); ?>
   </div>

    <?php 
        $current_id = get_the_id();
        $post = get_post($current_id);
        $new_title = 'New Title';
        afunction( $post, $new_title );
    ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

You will have to refresh at least once to see the change. If you manually change your theme file, you would have to refresh twice. Once to load the changed file, a second time to perform the update. To avoid that, you would need to perform a POST request (see the WordPress [HTTP API](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API)), or something to that effect.

This is not something someone normally would do with WordPress. But I can imagine some situations when it would be appropriate. Generally, a good practice would be to only allow logged in users to perform actions that update post data in your database.

**Note:** Take special care that if, as in your example index.php, you are using `if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();` that you are also closing that with `endif;` AFTER all of your code.

I also recommend that you review other examples of theme files from the default theme, and take care to review the logic of your PHP to check for problems.

So I hope that's useful.

Comment: this isnt working

Comment: the code you have given me works fine but the title isnt displaying ..when i look at the poststhe title is working fine but when i look the website it doesnt show me the post

Comment: Because you're updating the title on index.php, you should make sure you are in fact viewing the correct post. Depending on your theme, you may be viewing a Page instead of a Post. Then, make sure you still have <?php the_title(); ?> in your template. You also may have to refresh twice to see the change on the page.

Comment: yes there is the_title() but its not showing the post and title

Comment: I updated my answer with the complete theme code to use. It is working for me as I have tested it. If you are still having problems, it might be best to do more research, and when you have hit a dead end, post a new question with detailed explanation and complete sample code. You are probably already going to do this, but since your original question has been answered, you may feel it appropriate to mark this as 'accepted.'

Answer (score -1):

i'm not a very good coder, and even my english is not the best, but I think you must enter a title for every posts you create, so

```
  if ( empty ( $post->post_title ) )
    return;
```

is always false

i don't understand why you want to change the title with the code, it's not usefull!

maybe you can start with some tutorial on themes creation.. try [google](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIT549IT549&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=wordpress%20theme%20tutorial)